# Call contract from another account using web3.js

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I have a contract with which 2 accounts should interact.

The accounts are in the same node in `web3.eth.accounts`.

The contract was created by `accounts[0]`.

How can I call that contract from `accounts[1]` from web3.js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you call your function you can specify a from parametern in the  transactionOptions. Suppose you have a contract instance `contract` and want to call `vote` function. Then this calls it from account 1:

```
let account0;
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(result) {
  account0 = result[0];
  contract.vote(2, {
    from: account0
  });
});
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods